# How to send FB notifications using restfb api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to send fb notifications to users but getting the following exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.restfb.exception.FacebookGraphException: Received Facebook error
>   response of type GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request.
>   Object with ID '1543026015991325' does not exist, cannot be loaded due
>   to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please
>   read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api (code 100, subcode
>   null)     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1197)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1112)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1053)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:964)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.publish(DefaultFacebookClient.java:444)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.publish(DefaultFacebookClient.java:469)
>     at FacebookIntegrator.main(FacebookIntegrator.java:33)

Please find the code below:-

```
FacebookClient facebookClient1= new DefaultFacebookClient(app_access_token);

FacebookType publishMessageResponse1 = facebookClient1.publish(user.getId()+"/notifications", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("template", "RestFB"));
```

Comment: so what is that ID? is it an app scoped id? is it from a user who authorized your app?

Comment: yes I am using my user id

Answer (score 0):

That ID is not a User ID, it belongs to a Page. You can´t send notifications to Pages, you can only send notifications to Users who authorized your App.

Test: http://www.facebook.com/1543026015991325